# On the main site, why are some user names pink?

Tags: support

I have noticed that on the main site, some of the usernames shows in pink, while others are in red. Here is an example:

[image]

As you can see here, the users Simchona and FumbleFingers' names are in pink, while the username John Tobler is in bright red. Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ones in pink are profiles you have visited.

Comment: Good God... Stupid me... Ty for the answer.

Comment: A clear example of PBKAC, heh :D Don't bash  yourself @ChaosGamer ΕΛ-Υ ēel-ū (but hey, what a horrible login... you really type that in everytime?)

Comment: @Kheldar nah, why would I make hard names that I couldn;t type? :P I just type in my email. But imagine if I had to type in my Username for everytime.